# Why the class does not have to implement all the functions in a protocl?

Tags: swift, protocols

I'm a newer to Swift. UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate have so many functions. If I have a UIViewController to adopt them, why don't I have to implement all the functions? In other languages such as Java, the class has to implement all the functions declared in the interface.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` are Objective-C protocols, not Swift protocols.

The distinction is important, because Objective-C protocols allow you to mark some methods as `optional`, meaning they do not have to be implemented by whoever conforms to them.

There is an old but still useful Apple doc on the topic [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html), but essentially:

```
@protocol XYZPieChartViewDataSource
- (NSUInteger)numberOfSegments;
- (CGFloat)sizeOfSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex;
@optional
- (NSString *)titleForSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex;
- (BOOL)shouldExplodeSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex;
@required
- (UIColor *)colorForSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex;
@end
```

(Taken from the link above)

The `XYZPieChartViewDataSource` protocol has three required methods. If they are not marked as either `@optional` or `@required`, they are required by default. Note that the attribute is applied in cascade until finding another attribute, so both `- (NSString *)titleForSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex;` and `- (BOOL)shouldExplodeSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex;` are optional.

The methods of `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` that you are not required to implement have the `@optional` attribute.

In Swift, it is possible to have protocols with optional implementations as well, but you need to expose your protocol to Objective-C with the `@objc` attribute, and the methods that are marked as optional must be exposed to Objective-C as well. This is what `XYZPieChartViewDataSource` would look like in Swift:

```
@objc protocol XYZPieChartViewDataSource {
    @objc func numberOfSegments() -> Int
    @objc func sizeOfSegmentAtIndex(_ segmentIndex: Int) -> CGFloat
    
    @objc optional func titleForSegmentAtIndex(_ segmentIndex: Int) -> String
    @objc optional func shouldExplodeSegmentAtIndex(_ segmentIndex: Int) -> Bool
    
    @objc func colorForSegmentAtIndex(_ segmentIndex: Int) -> UIColor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation you'll notice the functions are often marked as `optional`. For example; [tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview) has "optional" before the method declaration meaning you do not have to implement it.

Comment: Yes, I see they are optional. So if a method is not marked as optional and required, it must be implemented in the class. Is it right?

Comment: Correct Bruce, if you want a class to conform to a certain protocol and do not implement the required method(s), Xcode will give you a warning and provide a "fixit" to autofill the required methods for you.